# Is it possible to use the function-like macro version of a function instead of the function versions of the C standard library?

Tags: c, macros

Is it possible to ensure the utilization of function-like macro version of `putc` or `getc` for example instead of the function versions?

For purposes of optimization and speed of run time execution.

Comment: There's no requirement that there be a macro version. It's an option allowed to the implementor, so they can optimize it.

Comment: Assuming that there *is* a macro version (which as Barmar says is not guaranteed), you get it by default, simply by writing `getc(c, fp)` as you normally would.  As always in C, when a function-like macro is encountered followed by a `(`, it gets expanded.  It's only if you *don't* want the macro version that you have to do something special, like `#undef getc` or `(getc)(c, fp)`.

Comment: Speaking of function call performance next to stdio.h I/O functions is pretty senseless anyway. The function call overhead is negligible in comparison to the actual I/O. It's as if you are about to embark on a journey to Mars and worry about greasing the door of the space shuttle to make it open faster.

Comment: @Lundin: Though in the case of getc/putc, depending on the size of the buffer, only a small fraction of calls may actually do any I/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test if the macros are defined with `#ifdef getc` but if the macro is not defined, you cannot define it yourself. If the macros are defined, writing `getc(f)` expands the macro.

Whether `getc()` and `putc()` are implemented as macros, inline functions or regular functions is not a guarantee of performance. Modern compilers may even inline the code at link time in static builds. Before you waste time on hand optimising this, use a benchmarking tool to determine where performance bottlenecks really hide.

If single byte I/O is a real concern, here are some hints to try and achieve better performance:

- On POSIX systems, if the stream is read or written from a single thread, you can use `getc_unlocked()` and `putc_unlocked()` and friends to bypass the stream locking mechanism.
- Depending on how you access the file, it may be appropriate to read and write one block at a time instead of one byte at a time
- Consider mapping the file in the process address space using `mmap` or an equivalent system dependent API.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I shall rephrase this answer, but it does address the XY problem and the phrase *For purposes of optimization and speed of run time execution.*

Answer (score 4):

The C standard says that the standard library *may* provide macro versions of standard function, but it isn't *required* to do so.  So any given implementation may or may not have such macro versions at all.

If it does have them, then you can use them simply by writing `getc(c, fp)` as you normally would.  This is nothing special about the library, just basic C: when the name of a function-like macro is encountered followed by a `(`, it gets expanded no matter what; the preprocessor doesn't get to decide to expand some such macro invocations and not others.

It's only if you *don't* want the macro version, and specifically want the function version instead, that you have to do something special, such as `#undef getc` or `(getc)(c, fp)`.

Note that even if there is a macro version, there's no guarantee that it actually improves performance.  In many cases, it might make it worse.

Comment: Thabks for your answer dude!!